# Build gallery in drupal 7 in the way required

Tags: 7, views, taxonomy-terms, media

I have this requirement. I want some ideas before i start building this.

1. I need to have various categories of galleries i.e cricket, football, rugby. There are the main categories.
2. In the gallery home page i need to have a drop down of these categories. Once i select a category all albums under this category like under cricket -> cricket1 -> cricket2 should come up.
3. When i click on any of the album i.e cricket1 it should go to its own page and show all images under it.

Basically i have doubt like what all modules should i use and how should i go about this. 1 main thing i need is views and taxonomies. Can any1 give me some ideas how to go about this requirement.

Comment: You'll need to break your post down into reasonable questions. I doubt you'll get many responses otherwise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand well your question, I think that you can use:

> I need to have various categories of galleries i.e cricket, football,
>   rugby. There are the main categories

Taxonomy to content type/s related.
Documentation of Taxonomy http://drupal.org/documentation/modules/taxonomy

> In the gallery home page i need to have a drop down of these
>   categories. Once i select a category all albums under this category
>   like under cricket -> cricket1 -> cricket2 should come up.

Views with exposed filters (you can create a block to show view inside home page)
Documentation of views http://drupal.org/documentation/modules/views

> When i click on any of the album i.e cricket1 it should go to its own
>   page and show all images under it.

the same view results will address to your specific content.